# Reducing using/foreach/using nesting with a helper extension

Tags: c#, reflection, extension-methods

#### Problem statement

There are sometimes `foreach` scenarios that require *deep* nesting due to multiple disposable objects involved that look like this:

> ```
> using(..)
> {
>     foreach(..)
>     {
>         using(..)
>         {
>
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

or a real-world example from one of my applications:

> ```
> using (_logger.BeginScope().CorrelationHandle("TestBundle").AttachElapsed())
> using (Disposable.Create(() =>
> {
>     foreach (var item in cache.Values) item.Dispose();
> }))
> {
>     _logger.Log(Abstraction.Layer.Service().Meta(new { TestBundleFileName = testBundle.FileName }));
>     foreach (var current in tests)
>     {
>         using (_logger.BeginScope().CorrelationHandle("TestCase").AttachElapsed())
>         {
>             // body
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

I find this code is very ugly and there is virtually no other way of writing this (or it's just me and I cannot think of any).

---

#### Suggested solution

So, in order to make it prettier I created the `Using` extension that encapsulates the *outer* and *inner* `using`s within the loop.

Its body is identical to the `using/foreach/using` *pattern* I'd like to get rid of elsewhere:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{   
    public static IEnumerable<(TItem Current, TInner Context)> Using<TItem, TOuter, TInner>
    (
        this IEnumerable<TItem> source,
        TOuter outer,
        Func<TItem, TInner> inner
    )
    {
        using (new Disposer<TOuter>(outer))
        {
            foreach (var item in source)
            {
                using (var context = new Disposer<TInner>(inner(item)))
                {
                    yield return (item, context);
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

This is using a helper `struct` for disposing `TOuter` and `TInner`

```
public readonly struct Disposer<T> : IDisposable
{
    public Disposer(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public T Value { get; }

    public void Dispose()       
    {
        if (Value is IDisposable disposable)
        {
            disposable.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
            {
                if (property.GetValue(Value) is IDisposable disposableProperty)
                {
                    disposableProperty.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static implicit operator T(Disposer<T> disposer) => disposer.Value;
}
```

And here is the `Disposable` helper:

```
public class Disposable : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Action _dispose;

    private Disposable(Action dispose)
    {
        _dispose = dispose;
    }

    public static IDisposable Empty => new Disposable(() => { });

    public static IDisposable Create(Action dispose)
    {
        return new Disposable(dispose);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _dispose();
    }
}
```

#### Example usage

Now, when I have such a scenario, I can put everything inside the loop:

```
void Main()
{
    var numbers = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };

    foreach (var (item, context) in numbers.Using
    (
        outer: Disposable.Create (() => Console.WriteLine("Outer disposed.")), 
        inner: _ => Disposable.Create (() => Console.WriteLine("Inner disposed.")))
    )
    {
        item.Dump();
        context.Dump();
    }
}
```

Then, when I refactor the previous ugly piece of code with this extension it turns into this:

> ```
> foreach (var (current, context) in tests.Using
> (
>     outer: new 
>     {
>         Scope = _logger.BeginScope().CorrelationHandle("TestBundle").AttachElapsed(),
>         CleanUp = Disposable.Create(() =>
>         {
>             foreach (var item in cache.Values) item.Dispose();
>         })
>     }, 
>     inner: _ => _logger.BeginScope().CorrelationHandle("TestCase").AttachElapsed())
> )
> {
>     // body
> }
> ```

#### Questions

- What do you think of this helper?
- Would you say the code is now easier to read?
- Can the `Using` extension or the `Disposer<T>` be improved?

Comment: Rewriting C# again, eh? :-) Could you give an example where you would need this code fragment?  _foreach (var property in typeof(T).GetProperties()) /* ..  */ disposableProperty.Dispose();_

Comment: @dfhwze haha, as always :-P see the second quoted code, this is my current ugly use-case that this extension should replace. The refactored version is at the bottom.

Comment: This is a very specific construct: using -> foreach -> using. Wouldn't it be more reusable to make a using -> foreach, and then be able to nest several such patterns?

Comment: @dfhwze maybe... but my imagination is currently unable to project it :-[

Comment: In c# 8.0 there is actually no need nestling for using statements ;) See: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8

Comment: @HelloWorld this is nice! I'll definitely use it... someday, when it's official ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd argue that no, this does not make the code easier to understand. Instead of a combination of familiar general-purpose constructs (`using` and `foreach`), you now have an undocumented custom special-purpose construct `Using(outer, inner)` that must be understood before one can make sense of the code. This use-case seems too uncommon to be worth that trade-off.

The main problem I have with the original piece of code is that it looks like a 'camel' because of the `Disposable.Create` hump at the start. Your alternative is still a camel, just with a bigger hump at the front and a flatter one at the back. With a `DisposeAll` extension method, you could turn it into a dromedary. It's still a tall hump, but now the shape actually matches its single-loop nature:

```
using (_logger.BeginScope().CorrelationHandle("TestBundle").AttachElapsed())
using (Disposable.Create(() => cache.Values.DisposeAll()))
{
    _logger.Log(Abstraction.Layer.Service().Meta(new { TestBundleFileName = testBundle.FileName }));
    foreach (var current in tests)
    {
        using (_logger.BeginScope().CorrelationHandle("TestCase").AttachElapsed())
        {
            // TODO
        }
    }
}
```

Another thing you can do is to move the loop body to a separate method or local function.

Comment: haha, I like the _camel_ analogy.

Comment: I stole this terminology in my answer, I hope you don't have a patent pending...

Comment: @dfhwze: if I had, and it came to court, then we'd have a camel-case... ;)

Comment: ok, you both have good points for not using this _invention_ ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Pieter Witvoet it doesn't improve readability. What you could do, since I know you like lambda's, is make additional convenience helpers to reduce *camel* code.

> ```
> Disposable.Create(() =>
> {
>     foreach (var item in cache.Values) item.Dispose();
> })
> ```

```
Disposable.Create(cache.Values, (item) => item.Dispose());
```

Additional method:

```
public static IDisposable Create<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
{
    return new Disposable(() =>
    {
        foreach (var item in source) action(item);
    });
}
```

I am not a big fan of this:

> ```
> foreach (var property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
> {
>     if (property.GetValue(Value) is IDisposable disposableProperty)
>     {
>         disposableProperty.Dispose();
>     }
> }
> ```

Can we really assume all of the properties that implement `IDisposable` *want* to be disposed here? In addition, `property.GetValue(Value)` throws errors in this naive `GetProperties` call.